# Scriptcase line chart Y- axis scale issue

Tags: charts, fusioncharts

Anyone knows how to adjust the y axis in a line chart in scriptcase?
The image below shows the problem:
Instead of starting at 0 and finishing at 1k, I would like Scriptcase to auto adjust the Y axis scale - perhaps going from 840 to 1k.
I have looked for this option but can not find any answer to it.
thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You can explicitly set y-axis min and max value using yAxisMinValue and yAxisMaxValue attribute at the chart object level for example : 

    "chart": {
            "yAxisMinValue":"840",
            "yAxisMaxValue":"1000"
          }

    For details please check this snippet - 

 FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'line',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "yAxisMinValue":"840",
        "yAxisMaxValue":"1000"
      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Mon",
          "value": "899"
        },
        {
          "label": "Tue",
          "value": "952"
        },
        {
          "label": "Wed",
          "value": "963"
        },
        {
          "label": "Thu",
          "value": "874"
        },
        {
          "label": "Fri",
          "value": "862"
        },
        {
          "label": "Sat",
          "value": "906"
        },
        {
          "label": "Sun",
          "value": "999"
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  visitChart.render();
});
```